# Placement of adverb relative to verb

Tags: verbs, adverbs

What is the preferred choice below?

A) "The order was unexpectedly cancelled."

B) "The order was cancelled unexpectedly."

I am guessing "cancelled" is a verb and "unexpectedly" is an adverb.  (Please correct me if wrong.)  Is there a hard or soft rule about adverb placement?

Comment: Please go through previous posts RELATED to this Q. (see box in the right hand column of this page.)

Comment: See also a list of questions tagged [*adverb-position*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverb-position) (BTW If someone could suggest *adverb-placement* as a synonym that would be very helpful to future questioners. I don't have the rep to do it myself)